# Can Firebase MLKit be used to detect polygons?

Tags: java, android, opencv, firebase-mlkit

I need a camera preview action in an android app that will find rectangles and process them. How can I achieve this with Firebase MLKit?

Sidenote: I know how to do this with OpenCV however even lightweight calculations drops the fps tremendously. If someone can help me solve the fps problem in OpenCV or point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All pre-trained models that are part of ML Kit for Firebase are shown on the documentation page here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/

There is currently no pre-built model for detecting polygons in an image mentioned there.